# Benchmarking Javascript vs Actionscript

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, javascript-engine

Are there standard code snippets used for benchmarking Javascript engines vs other technologies?

Can you link to the JS benchmarking snippets described here http://blogs.adobe.com/avikchaudhuri/2012/01/17/the-v8-myth-why-javascript-is-not-a-worthy-competitor/

- SOR
- LUFact
- HeapSort
- FFT
- Crypt

Comment: The battle has ended. Those kind of benchmarks aren't relevant anymore.

Comment: I know that it says `Disclaimer: The following opinion is personal; it does not in any way reflect the opinion of Adobe.` but please don't trust `*.adobe.com` in the terms of what is better, as they're the owners of flash and therefore would obviously not encourage the use of JS (*even though this is a personal blog, it's still on their domain*).